# How to add text at the beginning of specific lines using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I want to add some text at the beginning of each line that is below a character. Using sed in the terminal.

For example. If I have a textA.txt

```
@PL123
abcd
+
linewithmoretext
@PL456
efgh
+
2ndlinewithmoretext
```

and so on,with many more lines following the same structure.

And I want my output to be: textB.txt

```
@PL123
PREFIXabcd
+
linewithmoretext
@PL456
PREFIXefgh
+
2ndlinewithmoretext
```

I have tried

```
sed 's/^/PREFIX/' textA.txt > textB.txt
```

but that inserts PREFIX at the beginning of ALL lines. But I want it to be more specific,saying that I want PREFIX at the beginning of each line that is below the line containing @PL.
Can anyone help me please? I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever `@PL` is found, read next line and prepend `PREFIX` to it.

```
sed '/@PL/{n;s/^/PREFIX/}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk '{print (prev ~ /^@PL/ ? "PREFIX" : "") $0; prev=$0}' file
@PL123
PREFIXabcd
+
linewithmoretext
@PL456
PREFIXefgh
+
2ndlinewithmoretext
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
sed '/@PL/aline'
```

and then

```
perl -pi -e 's[line\n][PREFIX]g'
```

and it worked too. But your codes are easier, so I will use them.